# Rumbling noise related to road speed

Tags: noise

There is a rumbling noise which is related to road speed. It is slightly louder when the steering wheel is turned. Could it be wheel bearings?

I have BMW 528i year 2000.

Answer (score 3):

That does sound very likely - it could be bearings, or as the volume increases when the wheel is turned it may be the universal joint.

Get your car propped up securely and spin the front wheels by hand. You may be able to hear or even feel whereabouts the problem is.

In any case, your local garage will be able to diagnose this very quickly and easily.