# Why does the car give rumbling sound when passed over the road with small patches made by crane's

Tags: noise

I have read this [question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/4785/rumbling-noise-related-to-road-speed) and this [question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1456/creaky-banging-sound-when-going-over-bumps) before posting but neither of them solves my problem because in my case the suspension is good and there is no bumps in mine.

I have a hatch back Maruti Suzuki Swift which I drive on normal roads with asphalt. But recently due to some construction work nearby there's crane marks on the road all the way and when my car moves on that it gives a rumbling noise in the inside.I had stopped the car for inspection of the suspension and shock absorbers and everything was fine.

When everything is fine then why did I get this noise is it normal to have some rumbling noise in the inside when you car is driven over the crane marks on a Asphalt road.

The rumbling increases with the increase in speed isn't there any way that I can avoid this noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description, it seems like you are hearing normal sounds of operation while running over rough spots in the road created by cranes running down the road and creating divots in the road which are equally spaced apart. This can cause an extreme amount of noise in the cabin as you drive. Here in the state of Virginia (and in other states here in the US), they intentionally put "rumble strips" just beyond the edge of the outside lane. This is there to get a driver's attention should the stray beyond what is normally the driving lanes. I will tell you it will wake you up fast!

My point is, if you don't like how these bumps in the road create the interior noises in your vehicle, I suggest you don't drive on these roads - find an alternative route to get you to your destination.

Comment: +1. Same in the UK - at times the road is resurfaced with a temporary layer that causes a different sound when driving over it. It's not the car at fault at all.

Comment: Will insulation help,ther's no bylane adjoining it

Answer (score 1):

Your vehicle is a light-weight-build mass volume vehicle and under hard conditions would be susceptable to drumming. Never the less, your vehicle should be inspected for suspension, wheels and hubs, steering and exhaust being present and correct and in servicable condition. The recent deterioation in your local roads may be emphasising an already present problem.